# 'QtWidgets not found'

Tags: c++, macos, qt, homebrew

I just did `brew install qt5`.

`qmake` works, but the Makefile does not, giving me back a fatal error with "*QtWidgets not found*", which I copied and pasted from the tutorial.

I understand this is a linking issue with the framework, but what I've tried this and it did not work:

```qmake
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.1-1/lib
LIBS += -framework QtWidgets.framework
```

The code is:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget window;
    window.resize(320, 240);
    window.show();
    window.setWindowTitle(
        QApplication::translate("toplevel", "Top-level widget"));
    return app.exec();
}
```

The .pro file is:

```qmake
SOURCES = main.cpp
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.1-1/lib
LIBS += -framework QtWidgets.framework


# install
target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/tutorials/widgets/toplevel
sources.files = $$SOURCES $$HEADERS $$RESOURCES $$FORMS toplevel.pro
sources.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/tutorials/widgets/toplevel
INSTALLS += target sources

symbian: include($$QT_SOURCE_TREE/examples/symbianpkgrules.pri)
maemo5: include($$QT_SOURCE_TREE/examples/maemo5pkgrules.pri)

symbian: warning(This example might not fully work on Symbian platform)
maemo5: warning(This example might not fully work on Maemo platform)
simulator: warning(This example might not fully work on Simulator platform)
```

Both of which I retrieved from the official site.

How do I link this correctly?

Comment: Just read [QtWidgets documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-index.html)

Comment: @O'Neil That helped, thank you! Not sure why this was not originally in the .pro file they linked then. I'll make sure to read each class doc for these now.

Comment: I think the correct parameter is `QMAKE_LFLAGS += -L<...>` instead of `-F`. You can also check [qmake variables documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-libdir-flags).